# Set User field on ItemAdding event receiver

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I am trying to set the value of the user field but it won't work. I have no problems with the other types of fields.

Here is my code :

I get correctly the "ManagerLoginName".

```
User manager1User = clientContext.Web.EnsureUser(ManagerLoginName);
clientContext.Load(manager1User);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
result.ChangedItemProperties.Add("Manager1User", manager1User);
```

I get an error on last line.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: There is no error at that point. But when item is added the columns are empty , and i get an error later on with the event receiver when items is added

Answer (score 0):

Even though `ChangedItemProperties.Add` is expecting an `object` as the second parameter you can pass user information in the format `UserId;#UserName`

Comment: Yes but would it be accepted if the column is type User. I have it defined as type "User" in Schema.xml and i pass it string . Would this work?

Comment: You can give it a go.

Comment: if not, try a value of type `FieldUserValue` instead of `User`